# How to avoid application specific configuration like mysql/jms queue/log4j from standalone.xml file in jboss as 7.1?

Tags: jboss7.x

I have an application running in Jboss-5.1 , here i have different xml files to configure my server, mysql datasource , log4j , jms queue etc . But in case of Jboss as 7.1  i have to put all my configuration in only a single file standalone.xml . How can I avoid using standalone.xml file as less as possible ?

Answer (score 0):

if you going to use persistence, in your project put a persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit name="postgresql-connetion" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="postgresql"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

and orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

    <description>Mapping persistence entity</description>
    <package>com.entity</package>

</entity-mappings>
```

in jboss-home/modules add eclipselink module (org.eclipse.persistence)
add a postgresql module, and you have to add java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS datasource and postgresql driver on standalone.xml, I know no other way to avoid it, maybe start multiple Jboss instance or clusters: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1952

Comment: I was trying to find out whether there is any way to avoid using <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0"> in standalone.xml . Like previously in jboss-5.1 i have my mysql-ds.xml file in jboss/server/node/deploy/ folder .

Comment: I think Redhat Jboss team created this new way for each instance, add modules and subsystems to help you faster develop but your applications are tied to this configuration, I think that for each distinct application you need other jboss instance and config its standalone.xml

Comment: You can't split up the standalone.xml, but you can still use your *-ds.xml files, https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration#DataSourceconfiguration-Deploymentof%5Cds.xmlfiles.

Comment: I created a mysql-ds.xml file and put it in the deployments folder , but in case of jboss-7 i could not configure the jdbc driver in this xml file . So i created a module mysql in the modules/ folder and then add that module as a driver in the standalone.xml . This is a little progress . 

I also want to use my log4j.xml file in jboss-7 rather then jboss-7 's own logging framework and also all the jms queue settings and security settings outside of this standalone.xml .

Comment: http://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_as_7_1_0_final_thunder_released_java_ee_6_full_profile_certified